# Why didn't Helm's Deep have a trebuchet?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-two-towers

I am wondering if there is a reason why Helm's Deep did not have a trebuchet(s).

[image]

There were trebuchets mounted at numerous locations throughout the city of Minas Tirith in Gondor, so the Gondorians believed that they were necessary for the defense of the city.

Why didn't Helm's Deep have a trebuchet?

Comment: Duplicate of [Have the inhabitants of Middle-earth ever used siege engines?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150576/have-the-inhabitants-of-middle-earth-ever-used-siege-engines)

Comment: @Valorum, I don't think it does, because if Gondor had them, why wouldn't the Rohans have them too?

Comment: Presumably you're asking about the movies, don't recall that level of detail about armaments in the books.

Comment: @ZeissIkon, so in the books, there were no trebuchets at Minas Tirith? I don't remember if there were or not, because it's been a long time since I've read them.

Comment: I don't recall mention of any specific weapons beyond swords, axes, and bow (individual weapons, in other words).  It has, however, been decades since I last read the books through.  If the question isn't closed as a dupe, one of the experts will be along shortly...

Comment: Why didn't they have a phased plasma rifle in the 40 watt range?

Comment: @Valorum, now I have an image in my mind of terminators marching towards Helm's Deep.

Comment: @Valorum It's just what ya see pal.

Comment: My impression is that siege engines were *offensive* weapons, not defensive ones. So the real question is, why did Peter Jackson put offensive weapons to defensive use in Minas Tirith? The fact that he didn't do so in Helm's Deep is just ordinary "that's how siege engines work".

Comment: Not sure how this is a dupe. Other question actually says only Sauron had catapults, when in the movies Minas Tirith clearly has them as well.

Comment: The only siege weapon I recall being mentioned in the books is Grond, the big battering ram used to breach the first level of Minas Tirith. But a search of the text reveals catapults were used by Mordor during the siege of Minas Tirith, but not anywhere else.  “Catapult” appears exactly once. “Trebuchet” zero times. The word “engines” is used 8 times always referring to the catapults deployed on the Pelannor

Comment: @ToddWilcox That is not correct; in addition to Grond, Sauron's forces has catapults and siege towers; Gondor was defended with smaller "engines" that sound like ballistae ("darts") and catapults ("shot").

Comment: @DavidW You might be right, I can’t find that in the text. “Ballista” appears zero times. “Siege” does confirm there were towers used by Mordor. Not everyone would consider them weapons, but either way they are nothing like trebuchets. “Darts” only appears five times, never in reference to a siege weapon. “Shot” in reference to catapult ammo only appears twice, once related to the heads launched by the forces of Mordor and the second time it’s “shot and dart fell thick”, which could refer to various ammo used by either side.

Comment: @DaveJohnson My reading of the accepted answer of the alleged dupe is that it has an answer to this question, so I have voted to close. The answer *does* explain why “good” fortifications were not defended with siege weapons.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Added an answer with the appropriate quotes to demonstrate that Gondor _was_ defended by smaller siege-type weaponry (or at least crew-served weapons).

Comment: @Martha In real life seige engines were also mounted on walls as defensive weapons, which would give them longer range than identical engines mounted on the ground and firing at the city or cstle.  For example, on June 25, 1218, Simon de Montfort, leader of the Albigensian Crusade, was killed by a stone shot from the walls of Toulouse while beseiging the city.  The stone was shot by a mangonal allegely operated by women and girls.  And in LOTR Anarian was killed by a stone shot from the Black Tower during the seige, in Second Age 3440.

Comment: @DavidW Again, you could be right. Tolkien definitely uses “dart” to refer to projectiles not cast by ballista. “Wild men and poisoned darts” and “smitten by some dart of the Nazgûl” being examples. The “shot and dart” that “fell thick” didn’t necessarily come from defenders, either.